# Is it possible to use a custom color to fill a cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the color index 20 to fill up some cells but it is not my preferred color for this project. I would use a custom light gray which is not in the color index palette. Is it possible?

This is my code:

```
Sheets("Panel").Range("E7:E31").Interior.ColorIndex = 20
```

Comment: `Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function

Comment: This is great thanks. Do you know how I can get the RGB color from a grey of excel?

Comment: You could take a screenshot, paste it into paint, then use the eyedropper on it, and then check the RGB values under custom colors...

Comment: Yes of course, I was wondering if there was a way to do it in excel.

Comment: Why over-complicate it?

Comment: `Debug.Print Range("A1").Interior.Color`?

Comment: @Gass I would suggest recording a macro where you set the cell colour to the exact grey that you want and then look at the recorded macro code to see the RGB index of colour that has been set

Comment: Try using `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show 1, 192, 192, 192`. In the dialog window select 'Custom' tab and play with the RGB values until you can like (the New one) it. The last three parameters are the RGB to be edited/checked...

Comment: @braX why don't you post that line of code as the answer to the question so I can accept it?

Comment: @braX there is a way of getting the RGB in Excel. Fill colour -> More colours.. -> in the top select second option from left to right (RGB Sliders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest way...

```
Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function

You can get the RGB values any way you like. MS Paint has that ability using the eyedropper tool.

Answer (score 2):

Try the next code to choose the color you need. For RGB colors press `Custom` tab:

```
Sub testEditColorDialog()
 'Create variables for the color codes
 Dim FullColorCode As Long, RGBRed As Long, RGBGreen As Long, RGBBlue As Long

 'Get the color from the active cell (it can be any cell...):
 FullColorCode = ActiveCell.Interior.Color

 'Get the RGB value for each color (possible values 0 - 255)
 RGBRed = FullColorCode Mod 256
 RGBGreen = (FullColorCode \ 256) Mod 256
 RGBBlue = FullColorCode \ 65536

 'Open the ColorPicker dialog box for the active cell interior color
 If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show _
               (1, RGBRed, RGBGreen, RGBBlue) = True Then
    'selected the DialogBox (the edited one):
    FullColorCode = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(1)
    
    'Set the chosen color back to the anlized cell:
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = FullColorCode
 Else
    'nothing in case of Cancel
 End If
End Sub
```

I am not the creator of the above code. I only adapted something found on the internet, some time ago, to work according to my needs...

Answer (score 1):

### Cell Color Picker

- You can apply the desired color to a cell and run the following program, select the cell and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or select `OK` and the color value is copied to the clipboard, waiting for you to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CellColorPicker()
    Dim rgAddress As String
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        rgAddress = Selection.Cells(1).Address
    Else
        rgAddress = "A1"
    End If
    Dim rg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rg = Application.InputBox("Pick a cell", "ColorPicker", _
        rgAddress, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
            .SetText rg.Cells(1).Interior.Color
            .PutInClipboard
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can you explain `CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")` please? I found this on google - https://bytecomb.com/copy-and-paste-in-vba/ - is this the reason? thanks, J

Comment: That's a great link. Exactly that: late binding. It's instead of manually creating a workbook reference to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library`. If you mean to study it definitely use early binding (create a reference) so you will have access to `Intellisense`.